# Cookies not being saved from jquery ajax

Tags: node.js, ajax, passport.js, session-cookies, restify

I have a rest server running locally and a front end server running locally aswell. The rest server uses restify and session-cookie with passportjs. This all seems to be working fine as im using Postman app to test the API where cookies are being found and saved:

[Postman app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iAMu.png)

But when i use ajax on my front end app to login, i do not receive the cookie. Or at least it does not seem to save. This is the ajax code:

```
$("form#login-form").submit(function(){
    var data ={
      email: $(this).find("input[name='email']").val(),
      password: $(this).find("input[name='password']").val()
    };

    var data = JSON.stringify(data);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: URL + "/login",
      data: data,
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: "json",
      xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if(data.error){
          console.log("logged in error:" + data.error);
        }
        else {
          console.log("logged in:" + data.LoggedIn);
          window.location.replace("/");
        }

     }
   });
```

But the front end acts like it does log me in with each page displaying the right user info and logging out works perfectly too, but i cannot find a stored session for the page anywhere in chrome or firefox dev tools.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried reading the cookie using  `$.cookie("cookie_name")` to check if its set?

Comment: @Varun It comes back as undefined

Comment: What is the use of `window.location.replace("/");`? @Tristan

Comment: Try using `window.location.reload()` if you just need to refresh the page